# Using Raspberry pi as I/O Board over the Network

Tags: networking, hardware, connection

I was trying to set up Jasper on my Raspberry Pi. While the programm was running fine I wasn't quite pleased with the performance.

So i was thinking to run Jasper on a more powerfull machine and the raspberry as some kind of I/O board for the microphone and speakers.

I have some other prjekts i wanted to try where the computing power of the Raspberry pi isn't quite enough but i need the ports on the pi.

Is there a way to connect my raspberry over the local network to my server who does the computing for him?

edit: I would need to send an audio file from the pi to my server and an other one back from the server to the pi.
But i think it would be easier if i could access the ports (USB, GPIO) directly from the server over the network.

edit: Sorry my mistake it's called Jasper and is an open source voice controll software. (http://jasperproject.github.io/#about)

Comment: Could you edit the question and include details of the data you want to send from the Pi to the server?

Comment: What is Jesper and Jasper? References/URLs is helpfull.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest thing to do is to use an Raspberry Pi Zero as a port expander for your computer like [here](https://www.raspberrypi.org/blog/gpio-expander/).
This takes advantage of the ability of `gpiozero` to access the GPIO pins of a Server via network. So it actually works with every Pi model on the network not just a Pi zero connected directly. I think you can enable the server in `raspi-config`. But for not I think it only works with Python.